# EF Core change isolation level programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm learning EF Core and trying to change the isolation level of a transaction instance.

Here is the code I set up a transaction instance with ReadUncommitted level :

```
var transaction = new CommittableTransaction(new TransactionOptions
{ IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted });
```

I tried the below code to make it ReadCommitted, but doesn't work as IsolationLevel property is read-only.

`context.Database.GetEnlistedTransaction().IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;`

How can I do it programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no API for that, either because not all platforms support changing the transaction isolation level in-flight, or because it's a very unusual thing to attempt.

For SQL Server you can do this (if you really want to) with TSQL, but normally you just select the transaction isolation level a the beginning of the transaction.

Comment: Just to add on your point - If you are changing the isolation level during the transaction then you may be violating some SOLID principles.